# Duplicate values in relation with duplicate entity QGIS

Tags: qgis, qfield

In QGIS/QField I have a mother layer linked by an UUID relation with other sister layers. It would be very convenient for me to duplicate certain entities of the mother in a way that the UUID of the mother and the sister layer would change (not be the complete replication of the copied layer). It would create a totally independent duplicated layer and permit me to modify the linked species in my forms (in other words to win time because a majority of species in the sister forms are already entered). Is there a way to to that?